# How can i select multiple value with like

Tags: php, mysql

```
$user=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from tb_user where user_login_id='".$_SESSION['SEEKER_ID']."'"));
$skill=$user['user_skills_id'];

$employerjobs=mysql_query("select * from tb_job where job_keyskills like '%$skill%' ORDER BY `job_id` DESC limit 10");
$countjobs=mysql_num_rows($employerjobs);
```

I have two table user and employee. have keep user key skill in `$skill` variable (php,mysl);
and want to fetch from emplyee table

Comment: mysql_extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: You are using the like keyword properly. What's your problem? Note that the way you are coding, you are exposed to SQL injection.  Use parameterized queries to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use concatenation with your `$skill` variable, the same as you did with `$_SESSION['SEEKER_ID']`, so that script processor will know that you want to use variable value and not its name.

I'm not sure, but have you tried:

```
$employerjobs=mysql_query("select * from tb_job where job_keyskills like %'".$skill."'% ORDER BY `job_id` DESC limit 10");
```